# Array.fill differs from literal 2D definition on assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays

Earlier I've been trying out the [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) function, made myself a 9x9 2D array filled with all zeros, and then I wanted to update the [3][4] value. And bam, values are updated for all of the fourth keys, of every key in the first dimension([0][4], [1][4], ...).

It took me a while to figure it out, but it appears that Array.fill somehow differs in definition than the literal 2D-array definition, or does it? Because that's where I'm no longer sure if I'm missing anything.

```
var arr1 = new Array(9).fill(new Array(9).fill(0));
arr1[3][4] = 1;
console.log(arr1);
//Every fourth key of the 2nd dimension are replaced with 1.
var arr2 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
];
arr2[3][4] = 1;
console.log(arr2);
//Only the third key of first dimension to fourth key of 2nd is replaced with 1.
```

**Update:**
This actually opened up a good way for me to learn a few things I would rather, know but not comply why or how. However, I think the question will now rather broaden on for "programmers", rather than the coding itself this time.

Comment: Arrays (like any objects) are always passed by **reference**

Comment: @hindmost Indeed, however this question made me realize I have some stuff, rather uncertain about the programming itself, so I will be broadening it on programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) at

> The fill method is a mutable method, it will change this object
>   itself, and return it, not just return a copy of it.

A workaround could be to use `for` , `while` loops

```js
var arr1 = Array(9);
for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  // create a new array object at index `i` of `arr1`
  arr1[i] = [];
  while (arr1[i].length < arr1.length) {
    // fill array at index `i` of `arr1` with value of `n` : `0`
    arr1[i][arr1[i].length] = n
  }
}

arr1[3][4] = 1;

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(arr1, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: For the question itself, this will be the answer. Because that it is better this way to be worked around. Thank you.